# Text drawn with DrawText() on certain background colors (when SetBkMode is TRANSPARENT) is unacceptably blotchy: How to overcome?

Tags: winapi, text, textbox, mfc, antialiasing

In a legacy MFC application, I am attempting to draw deep red (255, 26, 26) on a 'Carbon' theme background (97, 107, 136) in a dialog.  Although I am using [BCGSoft's MFC library](https://www.bcgsoft.com/bcgcontrolbarpro.htm) to wrap the code that draws the text, the essential code that performs the drawing of the text is the following:

```
    // CODE THAT DRAWS THE TEXT

    // Copied from BCGSoft's 'BCGPStatic.cpp' text-drawing routine

    // clrText is RGB(255, 26, 26)
    COLORREF clrTextOld = pDC->SetTextColor (clrText);

    // background is RGB(97, 107, 136)
    pDC->SetBkMode (TRANSPARENT);

    pDC->DrawText (strText, rectClient, uiDTFlags);
```

Problem is: The text displayed is unacceptably blotchy:

---

**BLOTCHY TEXT**

[image: Blotchy text!]

If I change the color (and nothing else) to a lighter red (255, 164, 164), the text displays just fine:

---

**GOOD TEXT**

[image: Text is OK]

Because the font is likely of relevance, here is the code that sets the FONT:

```
    // SETTING THE FONT

    CFont * currentFont = staticCtl.GetFont();
    LOGFONT lf;
    memset(&lf, 0, sizeof(LOGFONT));
    currentFont->GetLogFont(&lf);
    lf.lfHeight = 18;
    lf.lfWeight = FW_BOLD;

    // I have ALSO TRIED:
    // CLEARTYPE_QUALITY
    // ANTIALIASED_QUALITY
    // NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY
    // PROOF_QUALITY
    // ...and just leaving it unset
    lf.lfQuality = CLEARTYPE_NATURAL_QUALITY;

    m_staticFontRed.CreateFontIndirect(&lf);
    staticCtl.SetFont(&m_staticFontRed);

    // The following are specific to BCGSoft
    staticCtl.m_hFont = (HFONT)(m_staticFontRed.GetSafeHandle());
    staticCtl.m_clrText = RGB(255, 164, 164);
```

I have researched this extensively and attempted as many 'workarounds' as I can think of.  Specifically:

- Use `TextOut` instead of `DrawText`
- Set `SetBkMode(OPAQUE)` and simply fill the background with `FillRect` before drawing the text
- Remove `FW_BOLD` from the font
- As noted in the code snippet, attempt different 'qualities' in the `LOGFONT` (`NONANTIALIASED_QUALITY`, etc.)

**What can I do, using MFC / WinAPI (in C++, obviously) to get my choice of color for both text and background to work without the text being unacceptably blotchy?**

---

**ADDENDUM**

Based on @BarmakShemirani's comment, I zoomed in on the pixels and found that they are RED (after taking a screenshot as a bitmap).  Therefore, for certain it would seem, those pixels are being generated as RED on the monitor and simply not being perceived by the eye that way).

Here is a picture of the zoomed-in version:

[image: Blotchiness-gone-when-zoomed-in]

...The red pixels are present (blotchiness gone).

I now suspect that this is an issue with the MONITOR, and not with the way the pixels are being drawn on-screen or with the human eye.

Thanks to @BarmakShemirani!

---

**ADDENDUM 2**

I use my monitor in portrait mode, which is atypical.  I just rotated the monitor to landscape and the very same screenshot in my question is significantly less blotchy.  This leads me to believe this is mostly a MONITOR issue and not an OS or 'human eye' issue.

...I wonder if some monitors handle this situation better than others, or is this 'built in' to most monitors for some (good) reason?

Comment: *"If I change the color (and nothing else) to a lighter red (255, 164, 164), the text displays just fine"* It sounds like anti-alias is applied in both cases, it's only different by the way it perceived by the eye. Magnify the image to see if anti-alias occurs or not.

Comment: Wow - If you zoom in even on the screenshots above you find that in fact the red IS present in the **BLOTCHY TEXT** screenshot - so you are 100% correct - this is an absolutely amazing, extreme example of the eye playing tricks!  Do you also see the 'blotchy' screenshot as blotchy, or might this vary from person to person?

Comment: The safest way is to use default system colors. Microsoft supposedly researches this issue with test groups, and settles on specific color schemes. Personally I have trouble with the color combination in "blotchy text" image, I can hardly read it. It might be my eyes, or my monitor, or both. If you are selecting different colors it's best to provide the user an option to select different themes.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani - I added an addendum to confirm your assessment.  I now suspect this is a *monitor* issue, rather than an issue with the human eye...

Comment: I use my monitor in portrait mode, which is atypical.  I just rotated the monitor to landscape and the very same screenshot in my question is significantly less blotchy.  This leads me to believe this is mostly a MONITOR issue and not an OS or 'human eye' issue.  ...I wonder if some monitors handle this situation better than others, or is this 'built in' to most monitors for some (good) reason?

Comment: If you magnify the text you will see that antialiasing has worked the same in both cases which is of course expected. The only difference is the color and the way it mixes with the background. So it's the color combination that causes the perceived effect. The background has a relatively low red component while the red foreground has only the red component set to a value high enough. For the "transitional" pixels these are merged, and the result is that these pixels become too dark.

Comment: In addition there is not enough contrast between the red color and the background: the background has a "lightness" value of 117, the red foreground "only" 141, which is quite close (and coming almost completely from the red component), while the pink one as high as 210. So I would say that the algorithm and the antialiasing works well, and it's the color combination that causes the ugly effect. Not all color combinations are expected to deliver an acceptable result.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou It's interesting that the effect is different when rotating from portrait to landscape mode.  This leads me to think that this might be a monitor-related effect in addition to an OS-level antialiasing effect.

Comment: Well, this can make an difference, if the resolution of the two modes is not the same, and particularly in the case where the pixels are not perfectly square. For example, a 1920×1080 resolution on a 16:9-sized monitor features square pixels because the ratio is the same, while a 1280×1024 one on 4:3 display does not. What are the resolutions in your case?

Comment: My eyes hurt by looking at this color scheme. Please, please, never throw this at your users! ;-) I suggest to read a good article about [color theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_theory).